# fatal error: DHT22.h: No such file or directory

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, esp-idf-sys

I am work with espressif ide this id's shows an error

fatal error: DHT22.h: No such file or directory
How to solve this type of error and how to take a output

please guide me and try to solve this error and how to add a library file for this ide